# List Dates and customizing tables in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, modeling, m

I'm trying to Add Custom Column in Power Query with the objective to return a Table from a List of dates.

The syntax used is as follows below:

```
= Table.AddColumn(TypeDate, "AddTable", each Table.FromList(
    List.Dates([Date_begin],1,#duration(1,0,0,0)
    )))
```

where:

1. TypeDate is the name of last step in Power Query
2. "AddTable" is the name of added custom column
3. [Date_begin] is a column with dates to be considered as the start of my list

Although the syntax seems correct, Power Query returns an error described as follows:

```
Expression.Error: We could not convert the value #date(2021, 1, 1) on to Text.
Details:
    Value=01/01/2021
    Type=[Type]
```

Does anyone know how to handle this problem?
I'll show an image where Power Query shows the error.

[Select here to see Power Query interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZT5k.png)

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect for `Table.FromList`.  Try `= Table.AddColumn(TypeDate, "AddTable", each Table.FromList(
List.Dates([Date_begin],1,#duration(1,0,0,0)),Splitter.SplitByNothing(),{"Dates"}))` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is unclear

You want to add a column that has a table of dates for each row, using Date_Begin and Mes_Final?

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(TypeDate, "AddTable", each Table.TransformColumnTypes(Table.FromList({Number.From([Date_Begin])..Number.From([Mes_Final])}, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), {"date"}),{{"date", type date}}))
```

[image]